# Parsing variable to function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got an onclick event that sets a variable. I then want to parse this variable to a function.

The function is defined like so:

```
function priceset(obj, options)
```

My question is how do I parse a variable (The variable is called productprice) to the function and then use it within the function?

Comment: Can you post some code with comments what exactly you want?

Comment: What do you want to parse it to, an int type or a float type?

Comment: Why can't you just set that variable as a function to begin with and use it when you need it?

Comment: You mean you have a field in your page containing a string and you want to use it as a float ?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have float data types per se, only Numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a function like this:

```
function SayGreeting(msg, qty) {
    for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        // do whatever you want here
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Then, to call this function and pass some variables, you do this:

```
var num = 12;
var greeting = "Hello";

SayGreeting(greeting, num);
```

If your number is actually a string and you want to change it into a number, you can do that like this:

```
var num = "12";
var greeting = "Hello";

SayGreeting(greeting, +num);
```

The `+` in front of the string, will attempt to parse the string into  a number.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To make a float from a field value, you may use this :

```
var myFloatValue = parseFloat(myStringValue);
```